# How do I stop/interrupt Maven Invoker?

Tags: java, maven

I'm doing a little software for helping purposes in my work. I'm building projects via Maven Invoker: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html

But when I call `invoker.execute(param);` I cannot interrupt this in any way. The project is very huge and it gets about 5 minutes to build. If the user wants to cancel it after 2 minutes, he can't.

Inside this **execute** method, I can see a `Runtime.exec()` but I don't have access to this process.

Comment: Why are you using maven-invoker? Why should a user wan't to cancel a run? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The purpose of the cancel button is to terminate the process. Why the user would want to cancel it? Well... I'm using maven invoker because it was built for this use. Thank you.

Comment: Hm...What about using a CI solution like Jenkins etc. which has all that stuff already? What is the purpose of using maven-invoker ?

Comment: I tried to use Runtime.exec() at first, but I don't know why, the clean install stops at the middle. Then I did some research on internet and I found maven-invoker. It is very easy to use and really works. The only thing missing is a method like invoker.stop() or invoker.terminate(). I don't know this Jenkins.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't answer my questions: What is the real purpose of using maven-invoker? Why not using a CI solution ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't use CI solution because I don't know this. I'm researching right now because you said about it. I'm using Invoker based on my first research. Not because I think it is best.

Comment: Look, we have a software made in Swing, is it possible to use Jenkins as a library to help me? If I cannot use like that, this is not the solution.

Comment: Jenkins is not a library it's a continious integration solution to run your build (sheduled or triggered by commits in your version control system) where you can abort builds if you like (which i don't recomment) etc. cause currently it sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm not reinventing, I'm just using what already exists. This tool we have is a helper to a lot of things in our daily work. One of the menus is "Development" which I can select the 6 projects and click "Build all", then I can go get a coffee and wait till it is finished. If I do not automate this, I will need to have 5 mvn clean install and 1 mvn clean deploy, all manually. The issue is, is there a way to stop a method that is running a Runtime.exec()?

Comment: maven-invoker was not designed as continuous integration tool. Its primary use (from what I know) is running integration tests. Setting up your project as a multi-module build & using a CI system like Jenkins is a far better solution for the tasks you describe. We have a team building a Swing app using Jenkins & it works fine. I have many multi-module projects where I run 'mvn clean deploy' (in Jenkins or on my laptop's command line) & walk away to get coffee. If you are writing code to automate the build process, then you are working too hard, because Jenkins does this already.

Comment: Ok nice! As Jenkins is a War that runs in a Tomcat for example, my desktop Swing application should send a request to the running application in Tomcat? This is what I understood.

Answer (score 0):

It might be quite late to answer this but I came across similar problem so sharing the possible ways which i came across as they may help someone.

### 1. Using Thread Interrupts

Interrupting the `invoker.execute(param);` from a different thread say a worker thread and issuing an interrupt from the main thread which can listen to the user events. for e.g.

```
Callable<Boolean> c = () -> invoker.execute(param);
FutureTask<Boolean> f1 = new FutureTask<>(c);
Thread t1 = new Thread(f1);
t1.start();

if(user.wantsToCanel()){
  t1.interrupt();//this will send an interrupt to the thread spawning Maven invoker
}

while(!f1.isDone()){
  Thread.sleep(100L);
}

InvocationResult ir = f1.get();
```

### 2. Forcefully killing the executor process

Since `MavenInvoker` executes the maven build in separate process and we can cancel the build by killing the process from a different thread. trick here is to pass a key in maven request params to identify right build to kill. for e.g.

```
String buildName = "mvn-213";

//Spawning thread with the buildName
List<String> goals = new ArrayList<>();
goals.add("install");
goals.add("-DMvn_Process_name="+ buildName));
InvocationRequest invocationRequest = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
invocationRequest.setGoals(goals);



//From a different thread.
//kill the maven build when user wants to kill that.

String command ="kill $(ps aux | grep '"+buildName+"' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}')";
String[] commands = {"bash", "-c", command};
try {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
} catch (Exception t) {
   //do something
}
```

Both approaches above requires a separate thread to kill/interrupt the maven build.